# Does anyone know what is happening/happened to my Peperomia Obtusifolia?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, peperomia

[image]

[image]

I recently got this **Peperomia Obtusifolia** as a gift last week, and am wondering what these brown tips are. They are only on the underside of the leaves, and only some leaves have them. I am keeping this plant on a 2-3 week watering schedule, as it is in the winter, but when I received it, some leaves did have brown spots, but I pruned them off.

I did some research and still don't know what has caused these brownish tips and if they are harmful or not. I am keeping it in bright indirect light and have not fertilized it.

Also, there is some odd yellow speckling which I have kind of not worried about, but it's only on a couple of leaves (like 3 or 4).